# Pandas - search by non-unique sorted index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains millions of rows. I need to search by `index` that `is not unique`. It seems that the implementation of `.loc` is binary search `O(logn)` in my case (with a `sorted index`).

The issue is, this is too slow. Is there a way to retrieve all the rows for a given index in constant time `O(1)`? It should be possible with some sort of `groupby` maybe? The implementation behind should be a hashmap with the index as a key and a list of rows as value.

Example:

```
RowIndex RowValue1 RowValue2 RowValue3 RowValue4
1        2         2         2         2
1        3         5         4         3
1        5         5         5         5
2        3         3         3         3
2        1         5         6         1
```

Let's assume thar `RowIndex` is a sorted index. I want to get all rows for index `1`. That would return rows `#1, #2 and #3` (`df.loc(1)`)

```
RowIndex RowValue1 RowValue2 RowValue3 RowValue4
1        2         2         2         2
1        3         5         4         3
1        5         5         5         5
```

The issue is, this is currently done in `O(logN)` time. I need to somehow create a hashmap that would store the index as key as a list of row objects as value.

```
1 => [Row(2, 2, 2, 2), Row(3, 5, 4, 3), Row(5, 5, 5, 5)]
```

This way I'd be able to fetch all the rows in constant time.

Update:

I've tried `df.groupby(df.index).agg(lambda x: list(x))` in order to generate a quasi structure but It's taking too long.

Comment: Have you tried Boolean indexing? For example `df[df['RowIndex']==1]`. And generally, loop in Python is very slow so extension with C like numba is one of solutions.

Comment: @shimo I tried but it seems to be slower according to my benchmarks.

Comment: Sorry not helping. Now I think you could consult numpy or C extension...